# How do I avoid the loop counting an iteration while printing to the terminal?

Tags: c, loops

The question is:
Write a program Q3.c that does the following steps:

1. Initially prompt the user to enter the balance amount.
2. Ask the user to enter one of the following options:

○ ‘A’ followed by an amount.

■ On receiving this option, add the amount to the balance.

■ Display the balance.

■ Go to step 2.

○ ‘S’ followed by an amount.

■ On receiving this option, subtract the amount from the balance.

■ Display the balance.

■ Go to step 2.

○ ‘E’

■ On receiving this option, break from the loop and exit the
program.

This is my code:

```
int main()
{
    int bal,new;
    char x;
    printf("Enter Balance: ");
    scanf("%d",&bal);
    
  for (int a=1; a>0;)
    {   
        printf("%dEnter Option: ",a);
        scanf("%c",&x);
        if (x=='E')
        {
            printf("Exiting...\n"); 
            break;
            return(0);
        }
        scanf("%d",&new);
        if (x=='A')
        {
            //bal = bal + new; 
            printf("Balance: %d\n",bal+new);
        }
        else if (x=='S')
        {
            //bal = bal - new; 
            printf("Balance: %d\n",bal-new);
        }
       a++; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Every time I enter a value, the loop runs another iteration while printing, like this.
[image: Terminal output]

How do I prevent this?

Comment: You're only breaking out of the loop if the user enters `E`.

Comment: @irregardless, as I understand it, that’s by design.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19911966/7342859

Comment: regarding: `printf("Exiting...\n"); 
            break;
            return(0);`  the `return` statement will never be executed because the `break` statement will cause an immediate exit of the `for()` loop

Comment: regarding: `a++; `  This should be the third parameter to the `for()` statement, not dangling off the end of the loop

Answer (score 1):

regarding:

```
scanf("%c",&x);
```

this will only input the next character in `stdin`  which, every other time, will be a '\n'.

Suggest:

```
scanf(" %c",&x);
```

notice the leading space in the format string, which will cause the call to `scanf()` to consume any leading `white space`.

The result is that the loop only iterates one time for each user selected option.

Comment: Oh, so the \n was causing this issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's happening due to scanf reading newline character present in the input buffer from previous scanf read. You can avoid this by adding a `getchar()` after each scanf to read that trailing newline character. I would suggest using `fgets()` to read input into a string and `sscanf()` to read variables from that string.

Here is how it would look like:

```c
printf("Enter Balance: ");
char input[100];
fgets(input, 100, stdin);
sscanf(input, "%d", &bal);

for (int a=1; a>0;) {   
    printf("%d Enter Option: ",a);
    fgets(input, 100, stdin);
    sscanf(input, "%c%d", &x, &new);
    if (x=='E') {
        printf("Exiting...\n"); 
        break;
        return(0);
    }
    if (x=='A') {
        bal = bal + new; 
        printf("Balance: %d\n",bal);
    } else if (x=='S') {
        bal = bal - new; 
        printf("Balance: %d\n",bal);
    }
    a++; 
}
```

I tested it and it seemed to be working okay:

```
c-posts : $ ./a.out 
Enter Balance: 1000
1 Enter Option: A 400
Balance: 1400
2 Enter Option: S 30
Balance: 1370
3 Enter Option: A 300
Balance: 1670
4 Enter Option: S 20
Balance: 1650
5 Enter Option: E
Exiting...
```

If you don't want to use gets, here is the `getchar()` approach, it doesn't look that clean to me but it works:

```c
printf("Enter Balance: ");
char input[100];
scanf("%d", &bal);
getchar();

for (int a=1; a>0;) {   
    printf("%d Enter Option: ",a);
    scanf("%c", &x);
    getchar();
    if (x=='E') {
        printf("Exiting...\n"); 
        break;
        return(0);
    }
    scanf("%d", &new);
    getchar();
    if (x=='A') {
        bal = bal + new; 
        printf("Balance: %d\n",bal);
    } else if (x=='S') {
        bal = bal - new; 
        printf("Balance: %d\n",bal);
    }
    a++; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but is there no way to do this with "scanf"? I was given this question in a test and we weren't allowed to use "anything that hasn't been covered in the class".

Comment: Yes, there is. Could you please try adding `getchar()` after each scanf?

Comment: Ok, ill try it out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've updated my answer with getchar() approach as well. You can try it out and share feedback